# Angular ng serve throws error undefined (reading '100')

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

PS D:\freelancing> ng serve -o
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '100')
See "C:\Users\akash\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-HXRwUk\angular-errors.log" for further details.

In log page "C:\Users\akash\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-HXRwUk\angular-errors.log"

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '100')
at forEachCode (D:\freelancing\node_modules\http-errors\index.js:261:45)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at populateConstructorExports (D:\freelancing\node_modules\http-errors\index.js:259:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\freelancing\node_modules\http-errors\index.js:31:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

Comment: Have you yet got any solution for this?

Comment: just have same issue on nodejs app with expressjs today. Have you found any root cause ?